# What are the Fallout 4 Pip-Boy companion app network requirements?

Tags: fallout-4

I downloaded the Fallout Pip-Boy companion app, thinking I could use it offline simply by using the local connection that goes between my wireless printer and my PC. I believe it is technically a Wi-Fi connection, albeit one without internet, I thought it ought to work.

However, when I connect my PC and phone to that network, and then start up Fallout 4, the app says "cannot scan for connections please ensure Wi-Fi connection" or something like that; I don't remember exact wording.

Is it just something I'm doing wrong, or is this actually not able to use a non-internet connection?

Comment: Are you using any cheats or console commands?

Comment: No, but for testing purposes I have been using a self made quick start save. Basically I created a character, ran her through the beginning and saved just before exiting the vault to get started quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Wireless printers that function without a router generally use a special Wi-Fi mode, frequently called Wi-Fi Direct or Wi-Di. It is not a network connection at all; it's effectively a cable without a wire.

The Pip-Boy app is a TCP/IP program; you don't need an *internet* connection, but you do need a *network* connection. You may be able set up your computer's Wi-Fi card to create an *ad-hoc network* (I'm sure you can find instructions on another part of SE for that), but there's no guarantee your mobile device can connect to it.

If you are able to successfully create a network and connect to it with your phone, the Pip-Boy app should work.